# How can one compute this simple infinite product?

Tags: infinite-product

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit of a particular variety of infinite product/series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/limit-of-a-particular-variety-of-infinite-product-series)

Define $$F(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)$$ where $|x|<1$.

How can one compute $F(1/2)$? (Without an obvious polynomial expansion or brute-force calculation.)

This is sometimes called [Euler's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).

Comment: Some related [information](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/limit-of-a-particular-variety-of-infinite-product-series) (no 'closed form').

Comment: Quick simulation stops around 0.288788...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni that's a great source. Nearly as good as a closed form.

Comment: Glad it helped @AlecS but I fear we will have to close this as duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That product is not so simple as you think. Euler proved that $$F(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^kx^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}}$$
This problem arises in partition number theory and is called Euler's pentagonal number theorem.

Comment: @AlecS: This [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510054v2) from Bell may help you too.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I had begun reading it already. :)

Comment: @AlecS: a rather fascinating subject I'll admit...