# How to calculate a bound for this product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products, infinite-product

Consider the following product:

$$ \prod_{i=1..n} {\left(1 - {1 \over 2^i}\right)} $$

A numeric calculation, up to $n=20$, gives $0.288788370496567$. But how can I calculate its limit when $n$ goes to infinity?

Alternatively, how can I prove that, for every $n$, the product is larger than $0.25$ (or some larger constant)?

Comment: How about applying logarithm & then expand using $\ln(1-x)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I was trying that, but if you want the exact solution you don't want to approximate $\ln(1-x)$ with a Taylor series.

Comment: Have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705/result-of-the-product-0-9-times-0-99-times-0-999-times?rq=1

Comment: To add to Michalis fine link containing J.M.'s excellent answer, jmad's link to [Euler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) and GEdgar's to [Pentagonal number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) let's add this reference to [Finch's book on constants](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/finch-mathematical-5.pdf) ($Q$ in page 356-7) and the entry [A015083](http://oeis.org/A015083) of OEIS.

Comment: I now see that this question has already been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258067/how-can-one-compute-this-simple-infinite-product and here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/limit-of-a-particular-variety-of-infinite-product-series

Comment: To summarize: by the  Pentagonal number theorem, $(1-x)(1-x^2)... = 1-x-x^2+x^5+x^7-...$, and for $x=1/2$, taking the first 4 elements, it is easy to see that the product is at least 0.28.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\prod_{k=1}^n 1-{1\over 2^k} = {1\over2}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} 1-{1\over2} \left({1\over2}\right)^k\right) = {1\over2}\left ( \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}1-2^{-k-1} \right) \implies$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty 1-{1\over 2^k} = {1\over2}\left (\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}1-2^{-k-1} \right)$$