# How to find the value of the above product up to infinity?

Tags: inequality

$$P=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^r}\right)$$

How to find the value of the above product up to infinity? Though I think we can find the minimum and maximum values of the above product using Weierstrass Inequality. Let $S=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{7}{8}+\cdots$. Then
$(1-S)<P<\frac{1}{(1-S)}$; where P is the above product. But how to find the actual value of the above product?

Comment: I doubt there exists a closed form; it is actually equal to the Euler function $\phi(q)$ evaluated at $q = -1/2$ (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).

Comment: But is that true for any value of q where |q|<1?

Comment: You will not get an answer in terms of transcendental functions. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function. Your product P is $\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)_n$

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/104685/454

Comment: check out this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258067/how-can-one-compute-this-simple-infinite-product)