# How to compute $\prod_{1\le i\le n} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, limits

Could you please tell me how to compute $\prod_{1\le i\le n} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$? Especially, I would like to know its limit when $n\to \infty$.

Thanks

Comment: The last sentence doesn't make sense. Do you want the product, or do you want the limit? There is no in-between.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I would like to know the limit as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod+(1-2%5E(-i-1))

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/limit-of-a-particular-variety-of-infinite-product-series

Comment: @anonymus Thank you very much

Comment: @lhf Thank you very much

Comment: The limit is $Q$ in [Tree searching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TreeSearching.html), which has many different forms.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Okay, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right) = \exp\left[-\sum_{n,m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m 2^{mn}}\right]=\exp\left[-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sigma(k)}{k 2^k}\right] $$
where $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sigma(k)}{k 2^k}$ converges pretty fast to $\approx 1.2420620948124$. It follows that
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right) \approx 0.288788095. $$
For the acceleration of similar Lambert-like series, have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978329/44121), too.
The approach outlined by Marko Riedel (Mellin transform and approximation through the trivial zeroes of the Riemann $\zeta$ function) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/655235/44121) is also extremely interesting.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much