# Prove $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e^{sx}\sqrt{1+s^2}}}ds < \arctan\left(\frac1x\right),\quad\forall x\ge1$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

The question is to prove:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e^{sx}\sqrt{1+s^2}}}ds < \arctan\left(\frac1x\right),\quad\forall x\ge1.
$$
Numerically it seems to hold true. So I have made some attempts to prove this analytically but have all failed.

I also wonder if there is a systematic approach to solve this kind of problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually this originates from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879015/prove-that-int-0x-frac-sin-tt-dt-arctan-x-for-x0, which has not been solved completely.

Comment: How is it related? Do you mean need proof $${\cal L}(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}})<{\cal L}(\dfrac{\sin s}{s})$$

Comment: In the original post, Jack D'Aurizio deduced that $\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt = \frac{\pi}2 - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x + s \sin x}{\left(1+s^2\right)e^{sx}}ds \ge \frac{\pi}2 - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{sx}\sqrt{1+s^2}}ds $. Using this and the identity $\arctan x = \frac{\pi}2 - \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x>0$, we conclude: Once we prove $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{sx}\sqrt{1+s^2}}ds < \arctan\left(\frac1{x}\right)$ for $x\ge1$, it follows $\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt > \arctan x$ for $x\ge 1$.

Comment: Posted also on MathOverflow: [Prove $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e^{sx}\sqrt{1+s^2}}}ds < \arctan\left(\frac1x\right),\quad\forall x\ge1$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308511). I think [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) offers very reasonable advice on [meta-tag:cross-posting].