# How do you show $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}dt>\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}x-1}{x}+\frac{\left(1-e^{-x}\right)}{x^{3}}>\arctan(x)$ for $x\geq 2$?

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Problem :

Let $x\geq 2$ :
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}dt>\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}x-1}{x}+\frac{\left(1-e^{-x}\right)}{x^{3}}>\arctan(x)$$

I can show one of the side let introduce :

$$f(x)=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}x-1}{x}+\frac{\left(1-e^{-x}\right)}{x^{3}}-\arctan(x)$$

Then :

$$f'(x)=(-1/(x^{2}+1)+e^{-x}(x+3)-2)/x^{4}$$

We have :

$$e^{-2}(2+3)<2$$

So the derivative is clearly negative and it limits is zero so we have the inequality .

For the other side I have tried power series without any effect .Also in the second reference there is a link with exponential integral so perhaps we can use complex analysis .

Using @JackD'aurizio answer we can compare :

$$\frac{\cos\left(a\right)+x\sin\left(a\right)}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)e^{ax}},\frac{f'\left(xa\right)}{a}$$

Where :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\left(1-e^{-x}\right)}{x^{3}}$$

How to show it ?

Reference :

[Prove that $\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t} dt > \arctan x $ for $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879015/prove-that-int-0x-frac-sin-tt-dt-arctan-x-for-x0/4702374#4702374)

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html