# Convergence of $P=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5^k}\right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Convergence of $$P=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5^k}\right) $$

Will this product converges to finite limit?

My try:

we have $$P=1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5^2}+2\frac{1}{5^3}+\cdots+2\frac{1}{5^7}+\cdots\infty$$

Comment: that sum is not infinite and I don't know where you got it from

Comment: $$\left(-1;\dfrac{1}{5}\right)_\infty = \prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{5^k}\right)$$ so $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\dfrac{1}{5^k}\right) = \dfrac{\left(-1;\dfrac{1}{5}\right)_\infty}{2}$$ [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=QPochhammer%5B-1,1%2F5%5D%2F2)

Comment: Since $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{5^k}$ is convergent your product is convergent. For accurate approximations see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/655235/44121).

Answer (score 2):

Using [$\ln x\leq x-1$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm),

$$\ln P=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac1{5^k}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{5^k}-1\right)=\frac14$$

As $\ln P\approx 0.23$, the bound is quite tight.

Answer (score 1):

A possible fast way is to [note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria)

$$\prod (1+a_k)\leq\exp \left(\sum a_k\right)$$
and $$\sum a_k =\sum 5^{-k}\leq\sum k^{-2}<\infty.$$

Of course this approach works for all infinite products of the form $\prod(1+\frac1{a^k})$ as long as $a>1$

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended, but invoking Bertrand's postulate allows one to avoid taking logs:

$$1+5^{-k}\lt{1\over1-5^{-k}}\lt{1\over1-2^{-2k}}\lt{1\over1-p_k^{-2}}$$

so

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+5^{-k})\lt\prod_p{1\over1-p^{-2}}=\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^2}\lt\infty$$